# How to recieve a message in the bloc getter changeMessage (which is actualy works as a setter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart

There is a bloc

```
  final _message = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get message => _message.stream;

  Function(String) get changeMessage {
    if (value == 'error') { // value is undefined here - how to get it?
      _message.sink.addError('error message');
    }

    return _message.sink.add;
  }
```

and in a service method I run `changeMessage` on the bloc

```
  ... } catch (e) {
      aBloc.changeMessage('error');
      return null;
  }
```

Is it possible to get passed value `error` in the bloc getter `changeMessage`?
It will give a condition to put error in the sink.

Later it the view it give the ability to obtaine `snapshot.hasError` condition.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not simply writing a regular method for your `changeMessage`? What is the point of this weird getter? It's wrong in multiple ways and I have no idea how to fix it since I don#t know why you want it and what you want it to do in the first place...

Comment: @nvoigt well, is not it a standart rxdart implemented bloc pattern?

Comment: I have no idea what the standard implementation would be, but I see no advantage over a regular method that does what you want. Why not a regular method?